# Why isn't my form validating?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a form. Currently it has no special clean method, it just has:

```
def clean(self):
    logger.debug('cleaning')
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
    return cleaned_data
```

This isn't being called anyway, the log statement in it does not fire.

I have a standard pattern for checking the form:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        logger.debug(form.non_field_errors())
        logger.debug(form.errors)
        logger.debug('form did not validate')
```

I also render field errors and non-field errors in the template, but they're all empty, and the log statements are blank. How can I find out what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you add the form definition? I don't see anything obviously wrong here.

Comment: And additionally, the view code (specifically, what do you pass as data) would be interesting too

Comment: or, if you can, try to debug it with `pdb` inside your else block

Comment: @WoLpH It was a problem with `__init__`, which causes validation to fail but doesn't provide helpful output anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `__init__` method. I was not passing the right information to `__init__`, which caused this strange behaviour.

Interestingly if you `__init__` the form wrong it won't throw an error, or give you useful validation error messages!

Comment: That is true. Specifically, if the `data` argument (which is why I asked for the view) is an empty dictionary it will not validate but will not always give helpful errors. With required form fields you'll get an error, but otherwise none.